# How to use "lapply" and "outer" together?

Tags: r, lapply

A very short question:

```
X <- data.frame(x = runif(10), y = runif(10))
lapply(X, outer, Y = 0:2, FUN = "^")
```

The `FUN` should really be passed to `outer` as an additional parameter, but R will assume it is the function fed to `lapply`.

Is there anyway to get around this, besides

```
fun <- function (x) outer(x, 0:2, "^")
lapply(X, fun)
```

or

```
vecX <- split(outer(unlist(X), 0:2, "^"), gl(2, 10, labels = names(X)))
lapply(vecX, matrix, nrow = nrow(X))
```

Comment: Though it's not the safest in general, exploiting the `...` works: `lapply(X, outer, Y = 0:2, "^")` will do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I am getting stupid after being less active in answering questions... Just pass everything in by position, to disable argument matching by names.

```
lapply(X, outer, 0:2, "^")
```